# Right-Click and Left-Click behavior when selecting an item in the tree view -- Version 6 vs 7

Tags: autodesk-forge

In version 6, when you select an item in the tree view and right click on it, you could see a full menu (Isolate, hide selected, show all objects, etc.). In version 7, you can see only one action in the menu (show all objects); in this version, you have to select an object with "SHIFT + left-click" first and then right click in order to see the full menu. I am wondering if I can make the behavior like version 6, or modify the behavior of right click or left click when selecting an item in the tree view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can config the left click behavior of the Model Browser to select the node, then right click to see all the options:

```
NOP_VIEWER.modelstructure.clickConfig.click.onObject=["toggleMultipleOverlayedSelection"]
```

[image]

See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customizing-modelstructurepanel-behavior-forge-viewer) for more details ...